# Most is vs most are

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which of these two is correct?

> Most company is private
>   Most companies are private

In general, should ***most*** be used with a singular or plural noun? And will the verb "be" be plural or singular?

Comment: No down/ close votes needed. See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/93306/14666

Comment: This question is way too basic for this site. It might be a better fit for our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Most* is what is called a determiner. [A determiner is](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/determiner) "a word, such as a number, article, personal pronoun, that determines (limits) the meaning of a noun phrase." Some determiners can only be used with either a countable noun or an uncountable noun, while others, like *most*, can be used with both countable and uncountable nouns. Uncountable nouns usually take a singular verb.

So, in your example, this is the correct form for your sentence: "Most companies are private." The plural noun is needed after the word *most* (*company*, referring to a business entity, is a countable noun, with a standard plural form [*companies*]), and then the plural verb is needed to construct a grammatically correct sentence.

But a sentence such as, "Most information is now obtained from the Internet." would take the singular verb (since *information* is considered an uncountable noun).

Interestingly, *company* can be an uncountable noun, but it then has a different definition than in your example. For example, "
Most company leaves after two or three days," is a perfectly acceptable sentence. In this case, *company* has the definition of a social gathering of guests or companions.

Here are a couple of additional links to information about [*determiners*](http://www.grammaring.com/determiners-with-countable-and-uncountable-nouns-some-any-no-many-much-few-little-etc) and [*uncountable nouns*.](http://bizwritingtip.com/?p=2427)

Comment: Uncountable nouns **usually** take a singular verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Can you give an example or three. I almost put that, but then couldn't think of an example that took a plural, off the top of my head.

Comment: From http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_countable_and_uncountable_nouns : **SOME UNCOUNTABLE NOUNS ARE PLURAL.
These have no singular form. e.g. clothes, groceries, thanks, jeans, police, trousers, scissors.** You may want to disagree with some of the list - I'm sure I've heard of 'a scissor' in US usage. And it's a syntactic feature - I'm sure the Chief Superintendent can readily find out how many police officers he's got under him, and 30 children will need 30 pairs of scissors. Furniture, clergy, people, headquarters, premises, means and cattle are some others.

Answer (score 1):

*Most companies are private* is the correct form.

Comment: But pray, why? :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of *most* as *the majority of*. Surely you would say *the majority of comanies are...* - wouldn't you?

Furthermore, *of the* is required if you limit the sample in any way.
A. Most men are stupid. B. Most *of the* men in that club are stupid. C. Most *of the* men in the world are stupid.

Sentences A and C seem the same in principle, but only A is completely unlimited. The same applies to uncountable nouns. D. I've put most of the sand in that barrel.